# Doing calculations in excel with Datetime format including milliseconds

Tags: excel

I have this column in excel. The format is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS` where `SSS` is milliseconds.

[image]

How can I make calculations such as subtracting two cells from each other? I keep getting an incorrect format error but I cannot find a format that includes date and time with milliseconds.

I am able to change the notation of the `DateTime` value but not split it into two cells.

Comment: my guess is the date/time is actually a text string and not a true date/time.  try changing the number format to general.  If a true date/time it will change to a decimal number.  If text it will remain the same and one will need to parse the string to create a true date/time.

Comment: The format is general by default

Comment: You can use `DATEVALUE`, but you'll have to massage the string into something Excel will accept as a valid local format, e.g. `=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,7,4)&"-"&MID(A1,1,2)&"-"&MID(A1,4,2)&RIGHT(A1,13))` (which would hopefully work on other machines as it uses ISO 8601, but you never know).

Comment: Then as I said the values are text and not true date/time.  One way to fix it is to use Text-To-Columns making sure on the third step to choose 'dmy' as the date config.

Answer (score 0):

Comments up above will suggest the built in test to columns method which works really well.  Scotts tip about the third step is imperative.   Jeroen's comments is using the DATEVALUE function which can be picky and somewhat dependent on your system settings.  There is a third choice of using DATE.  Jeroen's formula already does most of the work but needs a little tweaking.  The nice part of DATE is it is not picky nor reliant on system settings.

Important tidbit of info.  Excel stores dates as an integer with 1 representing 1900/01/01.  Time is stored as a decimal which represents percentage of a day.  So 0.5 is 12:00 noon.  Also 24:00 is not a valid time for excel but will still work with some functions.

The DATE function looks for 3 arguments to be passed to it.  Year, month, and day in that order.  So it is just a matter of pulling the applicable parts of your timestamp as a string out and placing them in the right location.  There is a Similar function for TIME.

Let assume one of your timestamps is located in C3

in D3 you can place the following formula to convert the date from text to an excel date:

```
=DATE(MID(C3,7,4),MID(C3,4,2),LEFT(C3,2))
```

In E3 you can place the following formula to convert the time from text to an excel time:

```
=TIME(MID(C3,12,2),MID(C3,15,2),MID(C4,18,6)
```

To get the information together its simply D3+E3.  however if you want to place the whole formula in one cell and avoide helper columns, the formula would look like:

```
=DATE(MID(C3,7,4),MID(C3,4,2),LEFT(C3,2))+TIME(MID(C3,12,2),MID(C3,15,2),MID(C4,18,6)
```

Now that the time in in excel format you can perform operations on it, apply formatting to make it look like you want, and use various excel functions with it.